# Rstudio Jsonlite nested List

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

New to Rstudio in general so some of my concepts are not clear. Trying to view data from OpenWeatherMap, on JSON files. They look something like this (shortened the data to view here).

```
[{"city_name":"X-Land"  
    "lon": -10.10,  
    "lat": 10.10  
  ,"main":{  
"temp":19,  
"temp_min":18,  
"temp_max":20 }  
  "weather": [{  
      "id": 800,  
      "main": "Clear",  
      "description": "clear sky",  
      "icon": "01d"  
    }],  
  "base": "stations", }]
```

Using jsonlite almost all the information display correctly

```
library(jsonlite)  
jsonData = fromJSON ("weatherfile.json")
```

The problem is the weather, it's a list? and when converted it all remain together.

[image]

I tried to use jsonlite flatten function with no results.
The question is, how do I separate weather into different columns (working with +15000 objects). Tried to google answers for a few hours and none of the results worked for me. Only found out that the problem is called nested list, and some of the solutions looks to be using dplyr, which confused me more.

This is what a row looks like.

> list(id = 800. main = "Clear". description = "sky is clear". icon = "01n")

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar JSON problem, and am using this solution using nested purrr::map() calls to pluck out specific nested elements:
[pull all elements with specific name from a nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64578972/pull-all-elements-with-specific-name-from-a-nested-list/64579426#64579426)

An example to pluck specific elements (the JSON is updated to make it valid):

*weatherfile.json*

```
[{"city_name":"X-Land",
  "lon":-10.10,
  "lat":10.10,
  "main":{
    "temp":19,
    "temp_min":18,
    "temp_max":20
  },
  "weather":[{
    "id":800,
    "main":"Clear",
    "description":"clear sky",
    "icon":"01d"
  }],
  "base":"stations"
}]
```

*example_1.R*

```
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

jsonData <- jsonlite::fromJSON("weatherfile.json", flatten = TRUE) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(weather_id = purrr::map(weather, "id"),
         weather_main = purrr::map(weather, "main"),
         weather_desc = purrr::map(weather, "description"),
         weather_icon = purrr::map(weather, "icon"))
```

If you want everything nested in `weather`, try tidyr::unnest_wider()` instead!

*example_2.R*

```
jsonData_unnest <- jsonlite::fromJSON("weatherfile.json", flatten = TRUE) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest_wider(weather)
```